# navigator.notification.confirm() - firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

Hi I have a loop in JSON to retry connection 3x before firing an error however sometimes I have 3-4 JSON requests and all of them can trough an errors so I have 3 alerts in my phonegap app.

EG.

```
function showJSONerror(xhr, status)  {

        if (xhr.status === 0 && localStorage["TmpAlertShow"] !== true) {

        navigator.notification.confirm('Connection error.\n Verify your network connection and try again.', confirmAction, 'Woops...','Try Again, Close');
        localStorage["TmpAlertShow"] = true;

        function confirmAction(button) {

          if (button == 1) { localStorage["TmpAlertShow"] = false; showPage(localStorage["TmpWebView"]) }  
          if (button == 2) { localStorage["TmpAlertShow"] = false; return false; } 

        }
}
```

I'm trying to find the way to close previous alert via JS or record the sate if the alert is already fired and not closed (prevent to display a multiple alerts)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like setting a global variable that is the count of requests currently running and then in your error function, say if the count is greater than 0 store the result in a global array and if not then process the errors for display.

Example:

```
var callsRunning = 0;
var callStatuses = [];
```

When running a call add:

```
callsRunning++;
```

When a call is done:

```
callsRunning--;
```

in your error function:

```
if(callsRunning > 0) {
    callStatuses.push(/*whatever you want to collect*/);
}
else {
    /*compile statuses for display of error*/
}
```

Comment: SO if I understand you correctly this is how this can be done?         `code var callsRunning = 0;
function showJSONerror(xhr, status)  {

        if (xhr.status === 0 && callsRunning > 0) {

        navigator.notification.confirm('Connection error.\n Verify your network connection and try again.', confirmAction, 'Woops...','Try Again, Close');
        callsRunning++;

        function confirmAction(button) {

          if (button == 1) { callsRunning--; showPage(localStorage["TmpWebView"]) }  
          if (button == 2) { callsRunning--; return false; } 

        }
}`

Comment: It seems I may have not understood the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

i've had a similar problem before

I used to resolve it http://underscorejs.org/#after

maybe give this a shot?

Comment: Yeah but this mean I have to use additional library on the top to only solve this issue :/

Comment: you could just mimic the same code if that is the only function you need?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but (un)surprisingly Android still does this sometimes for me as of Cordova 12.x, 12/2023. My solution for now was just setting a 1 second delayed boolean. I'm guessing there's likely a slicker way to handle but this seems to be working so far.

```js
// boolean to prevent accidental/multiple doConfirm calls (Android quirk?)
var doConfirmJustRan = false;

function doConfirm(confirmText, confirmTitle, confirmCallback){

  try{
    /* doConfirm just ran - don't run again yet! */
    if(doConfirmJustRan == true){
      console.log('doConfirm() tried to run again/too soon [' + confirmText + ']. exiting now.');
      return;
    } 

    /* do main navigator.notification.confirm stuff here ... */

    /* clear var in 1 second (?) */  
    doConfirmJustRan = true;
    window.setTimeout(function(){doConfirmJustRan = false;},1000);
    
  }catch(e){ /* ... */ }
}
```